# htaccess not trigerring when POST on index page [Custom PHP MVC]

Tags: php, apache, .htaccess, indexing, http-status-code-404

GOOD AFTERNOON

So i created a basic MVC.

```
**htaccess**
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Options All -Indexes

ErrorDocument 403 /display/errors/403.php

RewriteRule ^.*$ index.php [L,QSA]
```

Then index.php calls diferent objects to manage every page

So the problem starts when I submit a form in the root(/) page and the action atributte to the same root url (/):

[image]

```
**root page display**
<form action="/" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="nombre">
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit">
</form>
```

**Aditional info:**

1) When I submit the form to any other page like from here(/) to here(/contact) works fine.

2) When I submit the form to the same page but diferent from (/) (ej from /about to /about) works fine too.

3) In my app when a page is not found there is a specific class that manages the error, so if I go to /hi/dfdhhfhfh will have an error page that is working in every ocation.

So I guess for some reason the POST is being triggered before the htaccess but only in ( / ).

HOPE I CAN GET SOME HELP
THANKS

Comment: Try with: `Options FollowSymLinks`, `RewriteBase /`, `RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php [QSA,L]`.

Comment: not working =''(

Answer (score 0):

**FOUND THE PROBLEM AND THE SOLUTION:**

So, Apache generates an autoindex sometimes(don't know why and when,probably when a form actions before htaccess) witch must be called index. my MVC router has another name. So what ever the name of your router is, just add it in the first line of your .htaccess

```
DirectoryIndex /router.php
RewriteEngine on

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

Options All -Indexes

RewriteRule ^.*$ router.php [L,QSA]
```